# How to initilize different apps from the main appin extJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd, deftjs

How to initilize different apps from the main appin extJS

I have a main app where i am calling two different apps. like this in my app.json

```
"classpath": [
        "app",
        "${toolkit.name}/src",
        "${app.dir}/../appone",
        "${app.dir}/../apptwo"
    ],
```

The idea is keeping same header central region is need to replace with components of these apps based on soem routing.

Now the problem is the when i tried to load these apps from main app then class and service loader is not working in appone and apptwo. Where individually it is working fine.

here is application.js example of app1 where i am loading class and services.

```
    appone.ServiceLoader.loadServicesAndInject();
    appone.FactoryLoader.loadFactoryAndInject();
    appone.StoreLoader.loadStoresAndInject();
    appone.ContextLoader.loadContextsAndInject();
```

here is application.js example of app2 where i am loading class and services.

```
    apptwo.StoreLoader.loadStoresAndInject();
    apptwo.ServiceLoader.loadServicesAndInject();
    apptwo.ContextLoader.loadContextsAndInject();
```

Now what i have done is i have club both in in my main app. so these loders are loding but now it is not loading in individual apps. Any Idea how i can make use of these services and stores and context in indivual app in this scenario.

Comment: so you instantiate the loaders two times? in the main app, and then in the two individual apps?

Comment: previously they were in individual app. when i created a new app i have clubed both and add in main app.  But the problem happeing i am not able to use the loaders in individual app.s